# Not able to pass two parameters using hyperlink URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, parameters, hyperlink

Currently my Gridview hyperlink is passing one parameter in URL as show below

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkREQUEST_ID" runat="server" 
     Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.REQUEST_ID") %>' 
     NavigateUrl='<%# "~/StudentPages/viewREQUEST_ID_page.aspx?REQUEST_ID="+DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.REQUEST_ID")%>' >
```

Now, in the same hyperlink I need to pass another parameter which I am adding like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkREQUEST_ID" runat="server" 
     Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.REQUEST_ID") %>' 
     NavigateUrl='<%# "~/StudentPages/viewREQUEST_ID_page.aspx?REQUEST_ID="+DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.REQUEST_ID") & REQUESTER="+DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.REQUESTER")%>'>
```

but this is causing an error

> "REQUESTER" does not exist in current context

What's wrong here?

Comment: Looks like you are just missing `+"` before `&REQUESTER`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make changes:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkREQUEST_ID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.REQUEST_ID") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "~/StudentPages/viewREQUEST_ID_page.aspx?REQUEST_ID="+DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.REQUEST_ID") + "&REQUESTER="+DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.REQUESTER")%>'>
```